# Python module pptx and formatted input text

Tags: python-3.7, python-pptx

I'm using python pptx to present data form a MS Acesss database. In the Assess database I've a long text field with formatted text. When writing this text to ppt the HTML tags are in the text. F.e. text **Foo** bold in the long text filed gives Foo with the strong-tags in the ppt.

I want the text as formatted in the long text field in the same format in the PPT file and not with the tags. How can I do this?

Used code

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # create 1 slide ------
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
    slide.shapes.title.text = row[1]
    shapes = slide.shapes

    body_shape = shapes.placeholders[1]
    body_shape.text_frame.text = row[3]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Clarified what the question is.

Comment: You'll need to parse the HTML and map it to run formatting. There's an example here of what someone else did that worked. I would do it the same way: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/352#issuecomment-339358534

Comment: Thx Scanny. I will try this I hope later this week.

Comment: @Scanny, there are differences between the python interface for doc and xls but at the end it works. Thx for your answer!